# Is the copy constructor called when you dereferencing a pointer when passing by reference to a function

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dereferencing a pointer when passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347111/dereferencing-a-pointer-when-passing-by-reference)

Is the copy constructor called when you dereferencing a pointer when passing by reference to a function?

Here is a simple example

```
int& returnSame( int &example ) { return example: }

int main()
{
  int inum = 3;
  int *pinum = & inum;

  std::cout << "pinum: " <<  returnSame(*pinum) << std::endl;

  return 0;          

}
```

My Guess what happeing:

When we dereference pinum we would expect the copy constructor to be called, but since the function is passed by value this will not be called?

If pinum copy constructor was called then a temporary object would be produced and the reference of that would be used, which would be very bad news in the form of undefined behaivour...

So what does happen...undefined behavior?

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth that question was closed due to multiple typos

Comment: @MWright That question was closed because it was "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical".

Comment: flagged with a merge request.

Comment: @MWright - closure is not permanent. Votes can reopen questions our you can flag and explain that you've fixed it for a moderator to reopen it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the copy constructor is not called.

The dereference operator creates an lvalue referring to the existing object.  The reference parameter is bound to this existing object.