# Is (*i).member less efficient than i->member

Tags: c++, performance, dereference

Having

```
struct Person {
   string name;
};

Person* p = ...
```

Assume that no operators are overloaded.

---

Which is more efficient (if any) ?

`(*p).name` **vs.** `p->name`

Somewhere in the back of my head I hear some bells ringing, that the `*` dereference operator may create a temporary copy of an object; is this true?

---

The background of this question are cases like this:

```
Person& Person::someFunction(){
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

and I began to wonder, if changing the result to `Person*` and the last line to simply `return this` would make any difference (in performance)?

Comment: At this point you should much more worry about readability, and since `->` is the more common syntactic sugar, `(*i).m` is frowned upon in many places. Only if any profiling shows that there might be a problem related to this you should start worrying about its efficiency.

Comment: I'd expect the compiler to produce exactly the same result. You can answer this yourself, compile both codes to assembler and check the produced code.

Comment: I asked this question because of the *background* I described - many basic operators usually return a reference to self, and I see very often them returning `*this`;

Comment: `*p` is an l-value (you can do `*p = something;`). How could this create a temporary object?

Comment: @Angew Good point, I was thinking about `Person& p2 = *p;` and the possibility they dont refer to the same object

Comment: @KalamarObliwy There is no such possibility. The built-in pointer dereference operator `*` returns an l-value designating the object pointed to (you can think of it as a reference to it).

Comment: Some containers like [Boost's `fibonacci_heap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html) have a `handle_type` that doesn't even support `operator->` (probably only out of forgetfulness), so if you're being extremely general, you should probably use explicit dereferencing. I don't recommend it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you return a reference, that's exactly the same as passing back a pointer, *pointer semantics excluded*.
You pass back a `sizeof(void*)` element, not a `sizeof(yourClass)`.

So when you do that:

```
Person& Person::someFunction(){
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

You return a reference, and that reference has the same intrinsic size than a pointer, so there's no runtime difference.

Same goes for your use of `(*i).name`, but in that case you create an [l-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29), which has then the same semantics as a reference (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347111/dereferencing-a-pointer-when-passing-by-reference))

Comment: This is a good point about the size of return. Can you explain, what does `*p` do just by itself then? The result of it is a Person& or Person, or const Person&?

Comment: You get an `l-value`, which references the object's address, if I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347111/dereferencing-a-pointer-when-passing-by-reference correctly and according to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)

Answer (score 9):

There's no difference. Even the standard says the two are equivalent, and if there's any compiler out there that doesn't generate the same binary for both versions, it's a bad one.

Comment: The same for built-in types and user-defined??

Comment: @KalamarObliwy assuming no operator overloading, yes.

Comment: And for the standard smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`), the overloaded operators still behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's much harder to read and type, so you are much better off using the `x->y` than `(*x).y` - but other than typing efficiency, there is absolutely no difference. The compiler still needs to read the value of `x` and then add the offset to `y`, whether you use one form or the other [assuming there are no funny objects/classes involved that override the `operator->` and `operator*` respectively, of course]

There is definitely no extra object created when `(*x)` is referenced. The value of the pointer is loaded into a register in the processor [1]. That's it.

Returning a reference is typically more efficient, as it returns a pointer (in disguise) to the object, rather than making a copy of the object. For objects that are bigger than the size of a pointer, this is typically a win.

[1] Yes, we can have a C++ compiler for a processor that doesn't have registers. I know of at least one processor from Rank-Xerox that I saw in about 1984, which doesn't have registers, it was a dedicated LiSP processor, and it just has a stack for LiSP objects... But they are far from common in todays world. If someone working on a processor that doesn't have registers, please don't downvote my answer simply because I don't cover that option. I'm trying to keep the answer simple.

Answer (score 1):

Any good compiler will produce the same results. You can answer this yourself, compile both codes to assembler and check the produced code.