# Dereferencing a shared pointer and assigning to it

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, dereference

Is it ok to dereference a shared pointer, assign and assign a new object to it like so:

```
void foo()
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> x =
            std::make_shared<std::string>();

    bar(*x); // is this fine?
    // x == bsl::string("WHATEVER")
}

void bar(string& y)
{
    y = string("whatever");
}
```

Comment: You are making changes to the object managed by the pointer ( you are not making it manage a new object)

Comment: Yes, so the above code is safe then? I don't end up modifying a temporary or something like that?

Comment: Yes this is all fine

Comment: As an aside, consider using `auto` more. Repetition is error-prone.

Comment: @MartinF "_modifying a temporary_" What about it? Would that be bad?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is valid. [Operator `*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) returns the result of dereferencing the stored (raw) pointer.

Dereferencing a (raw) pointer does not make a copy or return a temporary: [dereferencing a pointer when passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347111/dereferencing-a-pointer-when-passing-by-reference)