# Why does 'this' need to be dereferenced in this case? (assignment operator)

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, this, assignment-operator

So this is an example [extracted from Bjarne Stroustrup's "A tour of C++ (2nd edition)] of a copy assignment of a user defined vector class:

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& a) // copy assignment
{
    double* p = new double[a.sz];
    for (int i=0; i!=a.sz; ++i)
        p[i] = a.elem[i];
    delete[] elem; // delete old elements
    elem = p; // here elem is the vector's data holding member array
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;
}
```

'This' is a pointer, so dereferencing it should actually give us the current object it points at. How does an object gets accepted as a return value in a case when a reference to said object is expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 'This' is a pointer, so dereferencing it should actually give us the current object it points at.

Yep.

> How does an object gets accepted as a return value in a case when a reference to said object is expected?

The same way any other reference is made.

```
int x = 3;
int& ref = x;  // just fine
```

> Why does 'this' need to be dereferenced in this case? (assignment operator)

The need to dereference a pointer to obtain the pointee, has very little to do with the function returning a reference type, other than to say that if you *didn't* dereference the pointer, you'd have to be returning the pointer, so the return type would have to be `Vector*`.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a pointer that points to the object that is assigned. The function returns a reference to the object. So you need to dereference the pointer to get the lvalue of the object.

Comment: So when the return type of a function is X&, the return statement of the function only needs to provide an object of type X?

Comment: @tudorarion there's no syntax tool in C++ meaning "a reference to variable X". The conversion is implicit, there's no ambiguity.

Comment: In other words, "yes".

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer type. Your function returns a reference to a `Vector`. To convert a pointer to a lvalue, you need to dereference it.

Comment: Technically a dereference does not give you an expression of reference type; it gives you an lvalue that refers [hah!] to the original value, and the type of that expression is `Vector` (not `Vector&`). But references are funny old things anyway...

Comment: You changed the wrong sentence :P The function returns a `Vector&` as that's the return type. But you said that dereferencing a pointer produces a reference, which is not true. (It doesn't vastly matter though)

Comment: And that's why I write things like "fixed, I think." That way I'm sure I understand what people are telling me. Okay, should be fixed for real this time. Please double check again and make sure I didn't mess up again.

Comment: Well the value category doesn't quite cover what dereferencing does, but close enough.

Comment: No, you'd need [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347111/dereferencing-a-pointer-when-passing-by-reference) to do that properly :D. Anyway, thanks for the friendly feedback.

Comment: Heh, yes. And ironically you've found a perfect dupe for this question