# Converting a Pointer to Reference, Costly?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How expensive is it to dereference a pointer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431469/how-expensive-is-it-to-dereference-a-pointer-in-c)

If I've got a pointer to an object, let's say `Object *ptr;`, and I want to pass that to a method of the form `void foo(Object& obj)` I understand that I need to write:

```
foo(*ptr);
```

But why dereference `ptr`? Wouldn't it make sense to just pass it `foo(ptr);`? I'm worried `*ptr` might be making a **copy** of the original object, or at the least not merely passing to `foo` the address to work with.

Can anyone clear this up for me? Is passing `*ptr` a potential bottleneck, for code that expects this to behave just as fast as if the function had been `void foo(Object *obj);` and called via `foo(ptr)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whether passing `*ptr` does make a copy or not depends on whether the called function expects an `Object` or an `Object &`.

In the former case,  a copy would be made. In the latter case (i.e., your case), *no* copy would be made.

Comment: So dereferencing via `Object a = *ptr;` results in a copy (as I had expected), but dereferencing via `Object &a = *ptr;` does not result in a copy? Interesting.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Exactly. `ptr` is a pointer to an object. `*ptr` is the object pointed to. Up to that point, no-one requires a copy. Assigning `*ptr` to a *different* object (`Object a`) requires a copy. *Referencing* the original object (via `Object & a`) doesn't.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: I just realized my comment above could have been worded better. Assigning `*ptr` to a different object requires a copy *because afterwards you have two objects*. Referencing the original object doesn't require a copy *because you still have only that one object*. (That's also the reason why dereferencing a pointer in itself isn't costly.)

Answer (score 14):

> I'm worried *ptr might be making a copy of the original object.

You're wrong. Dereferencing a pointer doesn't make any copy!

```
void f(Object & obj); //note it takes the argument by reference

Object *ptr = get();

foo(*ptr);
```

At the *last line* of this code there is no copy. The Standard gives you that guarantee.

However, if `f` takes the argument *by value*, then there *will be* copy.

The bottomline: the reference in the function parameter is used to *avoid* copy (often) or as ouput parameter (occasionally)!

Answer (score 1):

Passing an object by reference just passes the pointer so foo(*ptr) is correct and won't copy the object. Why dereference it? Because the function signature wants an object, not a pointer to an object. C++ is a strongly typed language.

Comment: C++ is not strongly typed – it’s actually not at all; but it’s static, you made a confusion.

Comment: it’s weakly typed since you can write such a function: `short add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }`

Comment: @sehe I think the problem is that "strongly typed" lacks a proper definition.

Comment: C++ is *static*, put that deep in your brains. Go learn Haskell, Caml or F#, then come back with a _proper_ definition

Comment: @skp what *exactly* is weakly typed in that function `add`?

Comment: So. C++ is strongly typed, but inherits weak implicit conversions from C. I agree

Comment: Hmm .. well it's strongly typed for a suitable definition of strong and compiler settings :) Anyway that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @skp the existence of implicit conversions does not necessarily mean a language isn't strongly-typed. You seem to be using the strong v weak typing nomenclature in a fundamentalist way. Here's a discussion on the merits of strong v weak with Guido van Rossum and everyone seems to agree C/C++/Java are all strongly typed. http://www.artima.com/intv/strongweakP.html

Comment: @skp C++ is strongly typed because you can enforce strong type checks for custom-defined types. It’s weakly typed (only) for built-in types and conversions inherited from C. *That subset* of the language is weakly typed. Everything else is only as weakly typed as the implicit casts that you (the programmer) put into your type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

To pass reference to a function, you have to pass the object like you do in value semantics. Pointers are not references since they are entity semantics (addresses).

If you dereference a pointer, you get an actual value, that can be embedded as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

References and Pointers are the same. But References have their own advantage and that is they can not be null ( though they can but it's kinda hard to make a null reference ) so you can omit the check against the nullptr. You can use . instead of -> which is a character shorter xD. About your question since the pointers are references are the same in the end there won't be any gains choosing one over the other. I mean the codes bellow are the same when compiled.

```
void foo(int &r) {}
```

and

```
void foo(int *p) {}
```

when you use a reference there will be a dereferencing in the background.
Hope it helped.

Comment: "pointers a[nd] references are the same in the end [when compiled]" - er, only in most (or is it all?) known implementations. The standard does not _require_ this. While maybe unlikely, it's _possible_ some platform could implement them in different ways, in which case, it might end up false that "there won't be any gains choosing one over the other" on such a system. Don't make statements like this about implementation-defined behaviour.